# Programmatically Disable GBoard Floating Mode?

Tags: android, gboard

I have an Android app that targets (among other things) the [Zebra WT6300](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/mobile-computers/wearable-computers/wt6300.html) (a wrist-mounted computer with a small display) running Android 13. There are a handful of places in the app where I need free-form text entry (typically as a backup to some nicer input method like scanning barcodes).

The default system keyboard is [GBoard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin&hl=en&gl=US). This is -- barely -- usable in its default state.

However, it is easy for the user to accidentally knock it into "floating" mode. While I'm sure this is awesome if you have a tablet the size of a billiards table or maybe some kind of Android-based touch-screen billboard, on the WT6300 the key pitch is approximately the Planck length. Better still, the trick(s) to putting it back are far from intuitive.

There appears to be no way to globally disable the floating mode of GBoard from the device settings on the WT6300.

Is there some way I can programmatically disable the floating mode within my app?

(My plan B is to tell customers to use the [Zebra Enterprise Keyboard](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/software/mobile-computer-software/enterprise-keyboard.html), which is platform-specific. That's OK for my specific case.)